How can I constrain a type to be a union of subclasses in Python?
I have a class, Foobar, with several subclasses, say FoobarAlpha and FoobarBeta.
I know how to define a type AnyFoobar = TypeVar("AnyFoobar", bound=Foobar) that will match any subclass of Foobar.
However, how can I define a type AnyFoobars that also matches union of Foobar subclasses? For instance, a type that would match FoobarAlpha, FoobarBeta and typing.Union[FoobarAlpha, FoobarBeta]?

This sounds like an XY problem. Why would you want to do this?

Why not just use the superclass?

"a type that would match FoobarAlpha, FoobarBeta and typing.Union[FoobarAlpha, FoobarBeta]" is... Foobar.

@user3840170 and @STerliakov are correct in the comments regarding a bound of Foobar accomplishing what you need. Likewise, AnyFoobar = TypeVar("AnyFoobar", bound=Foobar) is already sufficient for your request.
This is because typing.Union[FoobarAlpha, FoobarBeta] (changed to the modern syntax of FoobarAlpha | FoobarBeta going forward) is actually a subclass of Foobar from a type hinting perspective.
An important note though is that runtime is a different story. issubclass(FoobarAlpha | FoobarBeta, Foobar) raises a TypeError since FoobarAlpha | FoobarBeta isn't actually a runtime class. However, to a type checker, FoobarAlpha | FoobarBeta is as much a Foobar subclass as FoobarAlpha.
See this mypy playground for a demonstration of how AnyFoobars assigned to what you set AnyFoobar to accomplishes what you need. You can swap AnyFoobars for the alternative commented out declaration to achieve the same result, if a union bound is conceptually easier for you to understand.
